# iPadOS - SwiftUI in a Safari Extension Not Rendering Properly

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, safari, uiviewcontroller

I'm writing a simple credential autofill extension as a means of playing around with SwiftUI on iOS.  However, I'm finding that on iPadOS the SwiftUI `View` does not render properly.  My `CredentialProviderViewController` is called at the beginning of the extension lifecycle, and is responsible for loading the SwiftUI `View`.  It looks like this:

```
class CredentialProviderViewController: ASCredentialProviderViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func prepareCredentialList(for serviceIdentifiers: [ASCredentialServiceIdentifier]) {
        let services: [String] = serviceIdentifiers.map { $0.identifier }
        let autofillView = AutofillView(services: services,
                                        extensionContext: self.extensionContext)
        
        let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: autofillView)
        vc.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        vc.view.frame = view.bounds
        
        view.addSubview(vc.view)
        addChild(vc)
    }
}
```

My SwiftUI `AutofillView` is very simple and looks like this:

```
struct AutofillView: View {
    
    let services: [String]
    var extensionContext: ASCredentialProviderExtensionContext? = nil

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Text("LOCK SCREEN")
        }
    }
}
```

On iPhone, this renders exactly as I'd expect, with the words "LOCK SCREEN" appearing in the center of the `View` when the extension loads.  However, on iPad the `View` is displayed in a modal window and the contents are not rendered properly.  In fact, only the slightest bit of the "L" is displayed.  (See screenshot)

[image]

I'm sure I'm missing something or not instantiating my SwiftUI `View` properly.  I'm just not sure where.  Any thoughts?

Comment: As you turned of translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints then it is needed to add explicit constraints for hosting view.

Comment: @Asperi removing that line yields the same results

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding it into a containerview or as a subview, present the UIHostingController like you would a view controller

```
let services: [String] = serviceIdentifiers.map { $0.identifier }
let autofillView = AutofillView(services: services,
                                    extensionContext: self.extensionContext)
let vc = UIHostingController(rootView: autofillView)
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: false)
```